# TheOS Read from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

What is the best way to disable/enable tweak via code?Another question is : How i can read value from plist file? Thanks
My code is :

```
%hook somethinganother
- (void)somethinghere:(_Bool)arg1
  {
          NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Preferences/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), @"com.yourcompany.mytweak.plist"]];
                    if([[settings objectForKey:@"SomethingHere"] boolValue]) {
    %orig(NO);
} else %orig;
 }
  %end
```